# Getting mismatched types when compiling after STDIN and then math on input

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a rust program to convert an input temperature to celcius from fahrenheit or vice versa. I am still quite new to Rust, and the book mentioned to make this program as a way to learn.

When I try to compile the code I keep getting the error mismatched types. The errors can be seen immediately below, and my code is formatted beneath the errors.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> temperature.rs:12:28
   |
12 |     let temperature: u32 = temperature.trim().parse();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u32, found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `u32`
              found type `std::result::Result`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> temperature.rs:34:29
   |
34 |         let fahr_result: f32 = ((temperature * 9) / 5) + 32;
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected f32, found u32

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> temperature.rs:38:29
   |
38 |         let celc_result: f32 = temperature - 32 * 5 / 9;
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected f32, found u32
```

```
use std::io;

fn main () {
    println!("Welcome to the Temperature converter.");
    println!("Enter the temperature value, number only: ");

    let mut temperature = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut temperature)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let temperature: u32 = temperature.trim().parse();

    println!("Do you want to convert to Celcius or Fahrenheit? (Enter the number of your choice)\n1. Fahrenheit\n2.Celcius");

    let mut temp_choice = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut temp_choice)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let temp_choice: u32 = temp_choice.trim().parse()
        .expect("Fart in your butt.");

    if temp_choice == 1 {
        let fahr_result: f32 = ((temperature * 9) / 5) + 32;
        println!("{} degrees Celcius is equal to {} degrees Fahrenheit.", temperature, fahr_result);
    } else if temp_choice == 2 {
        let celc_result: f32 = temperature - 32 * 5 / 9;
        println!("{} degrees Fahrenheit is equal to {} degrees Celcius.", temperature, celc_result);
    } else {
        println!("Invalid Choice. Exiting.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `parse` returns a `Result` and you're trying to assign it to an unsigned integer. The `Result` type in Rust represents one of two things. A successful result, or an error result. If you want to get access to the underlying value, you'll [need to reference the documentation for a specific set of methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) to help with that.

Comment: Why are you parsing temperature as integer (`u32`), when you need to use it as float (`f32`) anyway? `std::parse` will parse floats and it will have the benefit of understanding fractional numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Rust's [`String.parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse) returns a `Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>`, not a string. The simplest thing to do is to use [`Result.unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) like so:

```
let temperature: u32 = temperature.trim().parse().unwrap();
```

Note that if `parse` returns an error result, `unwrap` will panic, so you may want to look at:

- [`Result.unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or) which allows you to provide a default value on failure
- [`Result.expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect) (as you are using elsewhere) which returns the `Ok` value of the result if it succeeded, or panics with the provided text argument if not

As for the other issue, this is due to the type being integer (`u32`), and so the maths is also integer (in which, for example, 5 / 9  = 0). A simple way to get around this is:

```
let fahr_result: f32 = (((temperature as f32) * 9.) / 5.) + 32.;
```

and:

```
let celc_result: f32 = (temperature as f32) - 32. * 5. / 9.;
```

As a bonus, the celsius result calculation isn't quite right due to the order of operations, as the multiplication and division will be performed before the subtraction. You can get around this by wrapping the `temperature - 32` in brackets like so:

```
let celc_result: f32 = ((temperature as f32) - 32.) * 5. / 9.;
```

Comment: Note that in your examples, you convert to `f32` after having done the computations on integers, so you still have the problem of `5/9==0`. You should do e.g. `(temperature as f32) * 9. / 5. + 32.`

Comment: Um, why not store `temperature` as `f32` from the start‽

Comment: @JanHudec I tried doing the float to begin with but I kept getting errors when trying to convert the value from a string to a float. So in my last futile attempt before coming to stack overflow I tried doing it as a u32 and making it a float when doing the math below. Neither of which worked.

Comment: @msbit thanks for the help. I was also unaware you could set the called variable as a different type by saying var as type, so that is much easier and something I will remember moving forward with Rust.

`let temperature: u32 = temperature.trim().parse().unwrap()
        .expect("Failed to parse correctly");`

This gave me the error "cannot infer type for 'T' and highlights the let statement before it hits the indented except on the next line. I assume this is happening because it sees an integer, but now looks for a result as well. if i exclude the expect it works fine until an error.

Comment: @undecisive when you get `cannot infer type for 'T'` it can be useful to [use a turbofish](https://matematikaadit.github.io/posts/rust-turbofish.html) just posting this here in case you weren't aware of it

Comment: @user25064 I was unaware of a turbofish, but the link you sent was pretty helpful in explaining what the turbofish is. However, when I try to add a turbofish ::<u32> to my temperature statement, after removing the u32 at the front, i get a expected 0 types but found 1 type error when using `let temperature: = temperature.trim().parse().unwrap::<u32>()
    .expect("Failed to parse correctly.");`

Comment: ah, that's because the turbofish goes on the parse function. The [unwrap function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) is not a generic function but the [parse function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.parse)  is generic over one parameter.

Comment: @undecisive, if you are having trouble `std::parse()`ing `f32` than *that* is what you should be asking about!

Comment: @JanHudec Thanks for the tip Jan. I'll remember that for next time. Like I said at the top of the post I'm new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're both reading  *The Rust Programming Language* and I have the same error. I solved it by:

```
let mut fbradley: f64 = match fbradley.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => 0.0,
};
```

The problem is that the output of `parse` is not a floating point number.

Comment: `fbradley.trim().parse().unwrap_or(0.0)` is simpler.  But silently substituting `0.0` when there is an error is probably not a good idea anyway.